# Wordpress custom fields feature is missing in my installation

Tags: custom-field

I cannot see the option to enable WordPress custom fields, and no, I have not installed or used Advanced Custom Fields Plugin for WordPress. I also disabled my functions.php (just in case) but with no luck. How can I see custom fields to enable it?

Comment: Does "Custom fields" checkbox is available for you on post edit screen? (Screen options on a top right corner of a screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mark this as answered. Go to any page or post and click on edit and follow the arrows below.

> By default, the custom fields option is hidden on the post edit screen. To view it, you need to click on the three-dot menu at the top-right corner of the screen and select ‘Options’ from the menu. Reference: [this site](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/)

[image]